# ASP.NET MVC JSON Post a HTML Form to a View?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have the following code:

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/personcontroller/getperson',
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#person').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      alert('yay');
    }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult getPerson(Person person)
{
    return new Json(person);
}
```

Html Form/Spark:

```
<form id="person">
   <input id="person.Id" type="hidden" value="${ViewData.Model.Person.Id}" />
   <input id="person.Name" value="${ViewData.Model.Person.Name}"></input>
   <input id="person.Age" value="${ViewData.Model.Person.Age}"></input>
   <input value="${ViewData.Model.Person.Gender}"></input>
</form>
```

When I POST the ajax call with the form, and put a break point in my action. The person object is not being populated with the input values, I feel like I am overlooking something really simple... Can you please point it out to me :|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inputs need a name attribute to post correctly. You should add a name attribute that matches the Id.

```
<form id="person">
   <input id="person.Id" name="person.Id" type="hidden" value="${ViewData.Model.Person.Id}" />
   <input id="person.Name" name="person.Name" value="${ViewData.Model.Person.Name}"></input>
   <input id="person.Age" name="person.Age" value="${ViewData.Model.Person.Age}"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: @tvanfosson: You mean id attribute.

Comment: Do i need the name attribute and the id attribute or will it work with just name :)?

Comment: My bad -- I just looked it up because I wasn't sure and the MVC helpers do replace the dot in the id with an underscore.  Not strictly necessary, but it helps with jQuery.

Comment: You only **need** the name, but if you want to access it with javascript having the id is handy.

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
public ActionResult getPerson([Bind(Prefix="person")]Person person)
```

**EDIT**

And as Michael Gattuso noticed, you should populate name property.